# Connect to RDS from EC2 instance with Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

Struggling with connecting to a database through python running on an RDS instance.

I've looked around at tutorials and I've tried this piece from amazon

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypwd',
        'HOST': 'mydbinstance.abcdefghijkl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

obviously I've substituted in my own details, but I'm not sure where to go from there. It also seems to using something called Beanstalk, which unless is there automatically on all AWS instances, I don't have. All I want to do is write some details to a table. Is there a tutorial or some advice anyone can give me?

Comment: This seems like the `settings.py` file of django project. Did you try running `python manage.py syncdb` to create database tables after that? Once you do that, you can run the local development server using `python manage.py  runserver`.

Comment: I'm not running django, so I had actually just pasted this into the `.py` file I'm running. Is there a way of connecting without using django?

Comment: In that case, you are looking for the `mysqldb` class of python. Check out [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, yeah I got it resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the data in a raw python script, you will have to use a suitable `mysql` connector class for python, just passing the database details raw into the script won't help.

So, check out [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples) and [mysql.connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) then.

Also, do ensure that the RDS instance is iteslf accessible from the EC2 instance, and there is no permission/access discrepancy causing the issue.

```
mysql -usa -p -hmydbinstance.abcdefghijkl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com mydb
#*sa* is the user in *-usa*
```

Comment: Thanks, for that. I'm making progress, but my connection is timing out using the connection code from dev.mysql.com. I've tried allowing all connectons in my security groups and I've double checked all the connection details.

Comment: are you able to connect to the rds instance at all, or is it just the python piece troubling you?

Comment: No it doesn't look like it `errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host><port number>' (110 Connection timed out)`

Comment: @Killian Give more details. Where are you running it and what is the exact commands you are using.

Comment: Also, does `mysql -usa -p -hmydbinstance.abcdefghijkl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com mydb` work from your EC2 instance?

Comment: @Killian The above command is just a check to ensure whether the rds instance is reachable from the ec2 instance or not.